# Please help protocol code that does not make sense

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

i'm stumped with part of this statement:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray <id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>>*sections
```

this property belongs to  NSFetchedResultsController Class.
although NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo is a protocol,  `id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>` is an object type that must conform to the NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo protocol. `id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>` is not a protocol so enclosing them in angle brackets
`<id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>>` makes no sense.
the statement NSArray `<id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>>` does not make sense to me as how can you make an object type id a protocol of the NSArray class. Can someone shed some light on this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax actually does not mean that the array conforms to any protocol. The notation is misleading. It only tells you that the values *inside* the array are `id` and conform to `NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo` protocol.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFetchedResultsController/sections) states:

> The objects in the sections array implement the NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo protocol.

It is for you to be sure that it will only contain values of the specified type and it is for the compiler to tell you that you are trying to insert non-compatible objects if you do so.

You might want to take a look at the last section in this [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html).

> If you’re writing an iOS app that uses the Core Data framework, for example, you’ll likely run into the NSFetchedResultsController class. This class is designed to help a data source object supply stored data to an iOS UITableView, making it easy to provide information like the number of rows.
>
> If you’re working with a table view whose content is split into multiple sections, you can also ask a fetched results controller for the relevant section information. Rather than returning a specific class containing this section information, the NSFetchedResultsController class instead returns an anonymous object, which conforms to the NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo protocol. This means it’s still possible to query the object for the information you need, such as the number of rows in a section
>
> Even though you don’t know the class of the sectionInfo object, the NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo protocol dictates that it can respond to the numberOfObjects message.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I very much appreciate it. i thought  NSArray <id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>>*sections is some new syntax that i missed. as an aside, why would apple write @property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray <id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>>*sections as a property declaration. it gives off the impression that this is indeed an actual property declaration in the protocol.

Comment: Wouldn't it be clearer to just indicate in the protocol declaration @property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *sections  and just explain that objects of the NSArray is of type id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>. Putting everything in one line gives off the impression that it is the actual declaration.

Comment: Interesting. Never came across this one before.

Comment: @DonGiovanni well, yes, it might be cleaner for you to understand. Yes, but it is not only for you, it also is there for the compiler. Maybe they should have choosen a different syntax. If you want to know why apple decided as they did, you would have to talk to them ;) I don´t know anything more than what I can find in the documentation.